# Use oracle instantclient-basic-linux with docker in Mac M1

Tags: oracle, docker, apple-m1, node-oracledb

i just migrated from my old mac to new one with M1 chip.

I have a middleware in nodejs (with SailsJs) that perform query in a Oracle DB. To avoid installing oracle client in the devs computers, we wrapping the project in docker, put the client zip in dir and install with an node:14 images.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.15.1

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libaio1 \
  && apt-get install -y unzip

#ADD ORACLE INSTANT CLIENT
RUN rm -rf /opt/oracle \
  && mkdir -p /opt/oracle
ADD ./lib/ .

RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
  && unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /opt/oracle  \
  && mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 /opt/oracle/instantclient \
  && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so \
  && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_HOME="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_LIB_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_INCLUDE_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 1337

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

With my M1 the build works fine, but when i call an API with a connection to oracle i got this error:

```
error: Services::OracleService::connect Connection fail
debug: WaterfallService open connection
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have arm64 Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

    at OracleDb.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:354:25)
    at OracleDb.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js:192:10)
    at Object.connect (/usr/src/app/api/services/OracleService.js:19:14)
    at Object.wrapper [as connect] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
    at Object.module.exports.connectdb (/usr/src/app/api/services/WaterfallService.js:5:17)
    at wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
    at nextTask (/usr/src/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5789:27)
    at Object.waterfall (/usr/src/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5800:9)
    at Object.awaitable [as waterfall] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:211:32)
    at Object.getAll [as area/getall] (/usr/src/app/api/controllers/AreaController.js:15:11)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:248:46
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:395:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
  errorNum: 0,
  offset: 0
}
```

```
Machine: Apple M1 Max
Docker: node:14.15.1 with ubuntu
oracledb: "oracle/node-oracledb#v5.5.0" 
sails: 1.5.3
```

Have you got any ideas to solve it?

Comment: The error message refers to the arm64 client, but you have the x86-64 client. Does it work with the [aarch64](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html) version - if 19.10 client is compatible with your DB version?

Comment: There is no ARM prebuilt binary for node-oracledb so the image will need the tooling to compile from source code.  A side comment: those three OCI_* environment variables are not used by node-oracledb.  Two of them were needed in version 1, but the third never was.  Similarly the Instant Client SDK hasn't been needed since version 1 (when ODPI-C was introduced).

Comment: Thank @AlexPoole the version 19.10 contains libclntsh.so.12.1, it's works!